# PIC Programming

Tags: pic, mplab

I truly apologize if my question is too amateurish or has been asked before (I searched and couldn't find anything).
I am working on a big project with a PIC MCU (MPLAB), I picked up where someone else stopped and he has no documentation of his code, it's horrible to look at. 
The main problem is that I can't find any records online for functions that appear on the code (i.e rdft, I know it performs FFT but I want to know more about parameters structure etc.).

Is there a good online source for library function for PIC? 
Or am I missing something and it's pure C written for embedded systems?

Thanks for your help.
Amir

Comment: You are not providing enough information. Is there any comment in the source file (file header/function header). Can you show a sample ? Usually there is no mystery about the arguments to an FFT.

Comment: Your starting point should be the [Microchip website](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/devtools/softwaresolutions/home.html) where, depending on which range of PIC devices you use (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit), there is sample code and/or libraries available, complete with documentation and support forums.

Comment: Sorry for not providing too much information. The code is copyright protected so I'm not allowed to share any of it here..

Thank you Roger, I will have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

With the provided information I cannot help with your particular code.

But answering your question:

> Is there a good online source for library function for PIC?

Yes there is you can find it in http://www.microchip.com/doclisting/SoftwareLib.aspx

Where it includes several libraries including some to preform FFT's.

> Or am I missing something and it's pure C written for embedded systems?

Well the IC provides several peripherals for different functionalities (SPI,I2C,ADC's, etc..) some IC's also include DSP's where one can implement FFT's making use of dedicated hardware on the IC's.
In the Software Lib's from Microchip you can find several libraries that provide an abstraction layer to access such hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not easy to answer your questions, but when I program some C-Code in MPLAB X, I have no libraries, for the MCU. Well I program some 8-Bit MCUs like the PIC18F4550 or the PIC18F46K20, etc... But you can use some standard libraries like math.h, strings.h or so to implement. But the rest like an I2C-Port or an RS232-Port I write by my self in small functions. For the 8-Bit MCUs, there are practically no libraries available from Microchip themselves, at least what I know. :-)
My tip for you: Tell us which Microcontroller it is (if it is an 8-Bit or so) and take a look at the data sheet of it. Also, you could make a copy on your desktop of the Code and try to clean it up (with tabs), that it looks readable to you.

Well I don't know how else I could help you. :-)